# Error al heredar de una clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, conda

Aprendiendo clases.

Tengo una clase denominada **market_data = class MarketData:**.

De la clase **MarketData**, heredamos el DataFrame **market_data.portfolio.df**, que tiene dos columnas. La etiqueta de las columnas es el nombre abreviado de los valores.

Queremos crear una clase '**class CreateDFAnalisys:**' que partiendo del DataFrame **market_data.portfolio_df**, cree otros dos, uno con los datos de la **columna 0** que denominaremos **value_df**, y otro con los datos de la **columna 1**, que denominaremos **index_df**.

Un vez conseguido esto queremos añadir a cada uno de estos DataFrames columnas con la **variación diaria de  la cotización**, **el rendimiento diario**, el **rendimiento logaritmico** y **el endimiento logaritmico acumulado.**

He creado éste código.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MarketData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.portfolio_df = pd.DataFrame()

                #Import quotes from multiple tickers from Yahoo
    def download_quotes(self):
        self.portfolio_df = yf.download("SPY, AAPL", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")['Close']       

class CreateDFAnalisys:
    def __init__(self, market_data):
        self.market_data = market_data
        self.value_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.index_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.portfolio_df = self.market_data.portfolio_df

    def select_analysis_df(self):
        lista_etiquetas = self.market_data.portfolio_df.columns
        self.value_df = self.market_data.portfolio_df[[lista_etiquetas[0]]]
        self.index_df = self.market_data.portfolio_df[[lista_etiquetas[1]]]
        return self.value_df, self.index_df

    def calculate_returns(self, data, name):
        data["variations"] = data[name].diff()
        data['Daily_returns'] = data[name].pct_change()    
        data['Daily_log_returns'] = np.log(data[name]/data[name].shift())
        data['Daily_cum_returns'] = data['Daily_log_returns'].cumsum().apply(np.exp)
        return data
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    market_data = MarketData()
    market_data.download_quotes()
    market_data.portfolio_df
    
    market_data = MarketData()
    create_df = CreateDFAnalisys(market_data)
    value_df, index_df = create_df.select_analysis_df()
    value_returns = create_df.calculate_returns(value_df, value_df.columns[0])
    index_returns = create_df.calculate_returns(index_df, index_df.columns[0])
    print(value_returns)
    print(index_returns)
```

Antes de ejecutarlo compruebo que **market_data.portfolio_df** es un DataFrame con datos correctos.

Ejecuto la clase  **class CreateDFAnalisys** y me devuelve el error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[33], line 30
     28 market_data = MarketData()
     29 create_df = CreateDFAnalisys(market_data)
---> 30 value_df, index_df = create_df.select_analysis_df()
     31 value_returns = create_df.calculate_returns(value_df, value_df.columns[0])
     32 index_returns = create_df.calculate_returns(index_df, index_df.columns[0])

Cell In[33], line 14, in CreateDFAnalisys.select_analysis_df(self)
     12 def select_analysis_df(self):
     13     lista_etiquetas = self.market_data.portfolio_df.columns
---> 14     self.value_df = self.market_data.portfolio_df[[lista_etiquetas[0]]]
     15     self.index_df = self.market_data.portfolio_df[[lista_etiquetas[1]]]
     16     return self.value_df, self.index_df

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5320, in Index.__getitem__(self, key)
   5317 if is_integer(key) or is_float(key):
   5318     # GH#44051 exclude bool, which would return a 2d ndarray
   5319     key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key, warn_float=True)
-> 5320     return getitem(key)
   5322 if isinstance(key, slice):
   5323     # This case is separated from the conditional above to avoid
   5324     # pessimization com.is_bool_indexer and ndim checks.
   5325     result = getitem(key)

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Este error, parece indicarnos que el DataFrame **market_data.portfolio_df** está vacío, cosa que, antes de ejecutar esta clase no era así.

Para mi sorpresa, ejecuto  **print(market_data.portfolio_df[:3])** y, efectivamente, está vacío. Luego tengo algún error en el código.

Agradeceŕe ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, comparte un código que podamos ejecutar para ser capaces de reproducir tu error. Por lo que veo en tu código no hay ninguna herencia, quizás debas modificar la pregunta.

Comment: El problema es que `market_data` es un dataframe vacío. Más que seguro te estás equivocado ya que creas 2 veces la variable y en la segunda no descargas nada, solo borra o comenta esa parte

Comment: Entiendo que quierese decir que estoy creando dos instancias de la clase MarketData . La primera es correcta. La segunda, hace que el DataFrame market_data.portfolio_df se vuelva a inicializar y quede vacío. Eliminando la segnda instancia, el secript funciona correctamente.